# Symfony HTTP PUT 2.6 strange behaviour (404)

Tags: php, rest, symfony, http, put

I have a Symfony 2.6 setup and I'd like to add a HTTP PUT request.
All my POST and GET requests are working, but with PUT I'm getting a 404.

HTTP GET Request: http://example.com/dfsfdfsfd
Response: No route found for "GET /dfsfdfsfd": Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT) (405 Method Not Allowed)

Nice! That's what I've expected, only PUT is allowed.

HTTP PUT Request: 
Reponse: The server returned a "404 Not Found".
This seems to be strange, a HTTP GET request tells me the method is not allowed, then I execute the same request with PUT method and receive a 404 error.

I've read something about browser compability on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html, but that only seems to be for HTML form limitations.

I've also checked my configuration files and found a nelmio_cors configuration key which allows the PUT request method.
Code:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE','OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

What am I doing wrong in this case? Is it a setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, had nothing to do with Symfony!
Was a server configuration problem (not accepting HTTP PUT).

Found   in my Apache configuration.
Added PUT to that list and the problem was solved.